# deserialize a URl in Django-Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm sending a GET request to my server with the endpoint as

`/api/v1/shipments/barcode/` where barcode is the string value, ie `/api/v1/shipments/140119758884542,526378589,GATI,110070,XXXX/`

When I see the server logs it encrypts the `comma` in the URL and replaces it with `%2C`, ie
`/api/v1/shipments/140119758884542%2C526378589%2CGATI%2C110070%2CXXXX%20`

Because of this I'm not being able to get the o/p that I want.  If I pass a barcode without a comma, it works fine. How do I deserialize the URL to make it work.

Here is my code

When I hit the `/api/v1/shipments/140119758884542,526378589,GATI,110070,XXXX/`, it should call my views.py function

```
def get_object_list(self,request): 
    #do something
```

how do I do it?

Comment: I think encryption here doesn't matter. Django decryptes urls for you. Logs are made on server level. Does `views.py` is a normal view or definition of resource? If its view, can you show `urls.py`?

Comment: @BartoszDabrowski - Its a defination of resource. What different should I do in order to hit that resource.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for rest of all who might face the same issue.

I just prepend the url like this and it worked

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [

        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/,-]*)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```